# ViewportSize in .runsettings?

Tags: playwright, runsettings, playwright-dotnet

I'm using NUnit and would like to start the browser in a custom size `ViewportSize`, I know that it is possible through overriding the `ContextOptions()` method, however I was wondering if this were to be possible by `.runsettings` also.

I've tried to add it below by going with the browser options documentation, but to be frank i can't really find a clear list on what is and isn't allowed within the .runsettings in regards to playwright or environment variables for playwright. Could anyone shed more light on this?

Code below is from the [playwright documentation page.](https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/test-runners#using-the-runsettings-file)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunSettings>
    <!-- NUnit adapter -->
    <NUnit>
        <NumberOfTestWorkers>24</NumberOfTestWorkers>
    </NUnit>
    <!-- General run configuration -->
    <RunConfiguration>
        <EnvironmentVariables>
            <!-- For debugging selectors, it's recommend 
                 to set the following environment variable -->
            <DEBUG>pw:api</DEBUG>
        </EnvironmentVariables>
    </RunConfiguration>


    <!-- Playwright -->
    <Playwright>
        <BrowserName>chromium</BrowserName>
        <ExpectTimeout>5000</ExpectTimeout>
        <LaunchOptions>
            <Headless>false</Headless>
            <Channel>chrome</Channel>

<!-- I tried it here -->
            <ViewportSize>
                <Width>2048</Width>
                <Height>1080</Height>
            </ViewportSize>

        </LaunchOptions>
    </Playwright>


</RunSettings>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The LaunchOptions section is a BrowserTypeLaunchOptions object which doesn't contain options for ViewportSize.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).